# Similarity of two self-adjoint operators

Tags: operator-theory

I am wondering whether the following is correct:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two bounded self-adjoint, positive and invertible linear operators such that $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$ and $AB=BA$. Can we say that $A$ is necessarily similar to $B$?

I just couldn't find an answer.

Thanks.

Math.

Comment: Where did you get the question?

Comment: In fact, I was trying to understand an example in some paper and if my question turns out to hold, then I am done.

Comment: Hint: Any two diagonal matrices commute with each other.

Comment: Daniel, are you saying that the result is not true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even if $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$, similarity sees multiplicity. For instance let 
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&2\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ B=\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\ 0&2&0\\0&0&2\end{bmatrix}. 
$$
Then $AB=BA$, $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)=\{1,2\}$, but they are not similar (for instance, because they don't have the same trace).

Comment: Great Martin! I also wanted two invertible $A$ and $B$ but this is perhaps easy to cure. Moreover, I forgot to mention that $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$ is also an assumption on my hand. Could you provide a proof now? Thanks!

Comment: Changed the answer to fit your requirements.

Comment: Yes! and Thanks! Martin you've been of great help! Math